# My first custom converter: why's not called?

Tags: jsf, icefaces, converters

I wrote my first JSF (1.2) custom converter.
I declared it in faces-config.xml (`converter-id` and `converter-class`), wrote the Java class implementing getAsObject and getAsString methods.
Then i put the converter in a page like this:

```
    <ice:selectInputDate id="ctldatanascita" 
                  value="#{beanrichiestaabilitazione.datanascita}"
          renderAsPopup="true">
      <f:converter converterId="cisConverterDate" />
    </ice:selectInputDate>
```

The class is istantiated, but the Converter interface methods are never called.
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't do IceFaces, so I can't tell from top of head if that is normal. But Googling on ["ice:selectinputdate converter"](http://www.google.com/search?q=ice%3aselectinputdate%20converter) leads me to this topic as first hit: http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/6163.page which confirms the behaviour you're seeing.

It als mentions several prerequirements and solutions:

- You need at least ICEfaces 1.7 DR2 or ICEfaces 1.6.2.
- Your converter needs to extend [`javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/DateTimeConverter.html).
- Or just use standard [`<f:convertDateTime>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/f/convertDateTime.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks again, BalusC! The missing point was extending javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter.