# how to validate input date against multiple patterns?

Tags: java, jsf

In my jsf application I know how to validate user input against one pattern in my `ice:selectInputDate` using a jsf converter:

```
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"  />
```

but how should I do if I want to let the user be able to enter a date in format: *"MM-dd-yyyy"* too?

I think this can be done extending DateConverter from jsf but I already tried with that and I fail. Do you have a valid example to **validate input date against multiple patterns?**

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I'm using jsf 1.2

Comment: @BalusC - I'm using JSF 1.2 for this project...

Comment: Thanks, it was after all not very relevant, the only difference would be the ability to use `@FacesConverter` or not. Anyway, please always mention the JSF impl/version in future questions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom converter which accepts multiple patterns by `<f:attribute>` on the component.

Here's how you'd like to have the view to look like:

```
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:converter converterId="multiDateConverter" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern1" value="MM/dd/yyyy" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern2" value="MM-dd-yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```

And here's how the converter can look like (for JSF 1.x, register it as

```
<converter-id>multiDateConverter</converter-id>
```

in `faces-config.xml` instead)

```
@FacesConverter(value="multiDateConverter")
public class MultiDateConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) throws ConverterException {
        List<String> patterns = getPatterns(component);
        Date date = null;

        for (String pattern : patterns) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            sdf.setLenient(false); // Don't parse dates like 33-33-3333.

            try {
                date = sdf.parse(value);
                break;
            } catch (ParseException ignore) {
                //
            }
        }

        if (date == null) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Invalid date format, must match either of " + patterns));
        }

        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ConverterException {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(getPatterns(component).get(0)).format((Date) value);
    }

    private static List<String> getPatterns(UIComponent component) {
        List<String> patterns = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            String pattern = (String) component.getAttributes().get("pattern" + i);

            if (pattern != null) {
                patterns.add(pattern);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (patterns.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide <f:attribute name=\"patternX\"> where X is the order number");
        }

        return patterns;
    }

}
```

Note that it only picks the first (default) pattern to redisplay the value. So in the above example, if you enter `05-10-2011`, then it get redisplayed as `05/10/2011`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the pattern `MM-dd-yyyy` isn't very common. Didn't you mean to use `dd-MM-yyyy`?

Comment: thanks a lot. I did exactly like you said, registered the converter also but seems it is not called for some reason... (I added logging in `getAsObject` and `getAsString` methods but it's not shown to jboss log). I'm using this f:converter stuff in an `ice:selectInputDate` component. If i put my initial f:converDateTime all works great...do you see any issue?

Comment: well...seems that the answer to my comment is another answer from you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515193/my-first-custom-converter-whys-not-called/5515298#5515298.

Comment: Oh yes, IceFaces components indeed require that for some or other reason. Sorry, didn't think about it since I don't use it. You're welcome anyway :)