# ace:dateTimeEntry converts invalid date to its another date

Tags: validation, date, ace-editor, icefaces-3

I have an ace:dateTimeEntry component as below :

`<ace:dateTimeEntry id="surveyDate"                                           partialSubmit="true" renderAsPopup="true"
                                               value="#{maintainAppointmentManagedBean.surveyNewDate}"
                                               pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true"
                                               valueChangeListener="#{maintainAppointmentManagedBean.surveyDateChangeListener}">
                                          </ace:dateTimeEntry>`

When I manually enter an invalid date such as 21544/10/2012, icefaces converts it to some acceptable format such as 10/12/2020 or similar. It must be doing some background calculation due to which it converts the invalid date to some other date. When it reaches my own validator, the date is already converted into some other date thus my validation has no effect and no message is displayed regarding the invalid date format. There is no JIRA raised to address this. Before I raise this as a bug has anyone else faced this problem or have any solution.

Also, the problem does not occur when `pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"`. It occurs only when pattern is `pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"`

Thanks, 
Dakshata Gulkhobare

Comment: Don`t know If this is a bug.. But an alternative is to write your own converter, too. Have a look here for some example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952222/how-to-validate-input-date-against-multiple-patterns

Comment: Well I got what it is.  if we provide a pattern such as pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" icefaces converts the invalid date to the  provided pattern. If this pattern is removed then no conversion happens and "invalid date" is passed to the validator and validation error gets thrown.

Comment: However removing date pattern is not a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding `lenientParsing="false"` into `ace:dateTimeEntry`
 and it works for me.

[dateTimeEntry](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v3_latest/ace/tld/ace/dateTimeEntry.html)