# Default hour and minutes where pattern = ''dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm''

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need a default  minutes and hour for p:calendar, but i need use pattern '' dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm ''

```
<p:calendar id="calendar" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.date}" showOn="button" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />
```

Comment: Hi Samuel - you’ll need to provide far more information here, as as it stands I have no idea what you’re talking about. Read this for example: [mcve].

Comment: I need to use the pattern "dd / MM / yyyy HH: mm", but I do not want the hours and minutes to be obligatory, I can put them by default if the user does not enter it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolvet the problem whit one pattern convertor, i saw in this link: 
[how to validate input date against multiple patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952222/how-to-validate-input-date-against-multiple-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

To have a default value for your time, you need a default value for your date altogether. Your calendar value is linked to a Date object in your Bean, so it must be set to a default value there. 
For example, with today's date at 8am :

```
private Calendar calDate;
private Date date;

// your bean's contructor
public MyBean()
{
    this.calDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.calDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    this.calDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    this.date = this.calDate.getTime();
}
```

With that setup, your calendar input with have a default value of today's date and the time set at 8am.

Comment: the validator from p:calendar don't let's communication jsf to java, resolved with one convertor pattern